# Substitutions in improper integrals

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, improper-integrals

I have a somewhat general question, but have trouble formulating it I will illustrate my question with an example, in the hope that someone can generalise this.

Consider:

$$I = \int_{0}^ \infty \frac{dx}{1+(2x+1)^2}$$

Let $t = 2x+1, dt/2 = dx$. If $x = 0$, then $t = 1$ and if $x = \infty$ then $t = \infty$. Hence

$$I = 1/2\int_{1}^\infty \frac{dt}{1+t^2} = 1/2 (\lim_{t \to \infty} \arctan t - \pi/4) = 1/2( \pi/2 - \pi/4) = \pi/8$$

I want to formalize the "$x = \infty$, then $t = \infty$" part.

It seems that we can do:

$$I = \lim_{s \to \infty} \int_0^s \frac{dx}{1 +(2x+1)^2} = 1/2\lim_{s} \int_1^{2s+1} \frac{dt}{1+t^2} $$

$$= 1/2(\lim_s \arctan(2s+1) - \pi/4) = \pi/8$$

> Is there a general substitution rule for improper integrals of this
>   kind?

Comment: You can write: if $x \to \infty$ then $t \to \infty.$

Comment: Yeah, I know. I want to formalize this step. That's the question.

Comment: The expression you wrote with an upper limit s on x and then convert to an upper limit 2s+1 for t is the formalization that you want.